# Moore machine state diagram and state table

Tags: state-machines

Is it me not understanding this table and diagram or something?
If in a Moore machine, the output only depends on the current state
Then why does the table for states F and H say the output is independent of the input?
At F, if the input is a 0 the state changes to I and output would be a 1
At F, if the input is a 1 the state stays the same at F and the output would be a 0

The state table does not reflect this?

The state table should show multiple outputs...

[image]

Comment: Is it because im stupid or something?

Comment: You're confusing "next state" with "output". The combination of current state and inputs determine the next state, but the output doesn't change until it moves to that next state. The output depends ONLY on the current state.

Comment: So what youre saying is if i am just landed on F, the current output is 0. I set an input of 1, the output is still 0, i set an input of 0 at t1, the output is still 0 at t1+deltat until t2 where the state is I and the output is 1?

Comment: Very ambiguous to me

Comment: Note that *"the output is independent of the input"* and *"the output only depends on the current state"* are not contradicting statements, they are just two independent statements.

Comment: What this says to me is that the ordering of inputs, state change and output change is important. Where the occurrence sequence given an input change is: Input changes -> state changes -> output changes

Comment: Which i have previously been told that the ordering is not important from this same site

Comment: Since the output is tied to a state..
Changing the input cannot change an output until the state changes

Comment: @Oldfart, they aren't totally independent. The first one can be inferred from the second one.

Answer (score 2):

True to say "In a Moore machine the output only depends on the current state". In a Moore machine the output will not respond to a change in the input until the next clock pulse when the state moves to the next state (a new present state). Therefore a Moore machine only has one possible output during each present state.

In a Mealy machine the output will respond immediately (almost) to a change in the input and therefore can have more than one possible output during each present state.

To summarize - The output of the Mealy machine is a function of both the current state variable and the input variable whereas the output of a Moore machine is only a function of the current state variable.

Answer (score 1):

> the output only depends on the current state Then why does the table for states F and H say the output is independent of the input?

Because if it depends **only** on the current state, then it can't also depend on the inputs.

The inputs determine whether you get to a certain state. But after you're in that state the output only depends on the state. Assuming a typical clocked design, the output doesn't change instantly if the inputs change before the next clock edge. And it only changes at the clock edge if the changed inputs lead to a new state.

Comment: A Moore machine doesn't have to have to be clocked.

Comment: @Finbarr, edited.

Comment: Have already figured this out, clearly trying to get free browny points. Should be negged

Comment: @LuckyBlueCherry, somebody has to post an actual answer or the question will be bumped to the front page indefinitely. If Finbarr wants to post their comment as an answer, and expresses it equally or more clearly, I will delete my answer.